# shake is not work in windows phone 8 phonegap app

Tags: jquery, cordova, windows-phone-8, shake

I am newbie for windows phonegap app.   I make a App which based on phone-gap.
 It completely working fine with shake when I attached a device(wp8) with the system and then release a app, but when i stop the debug or release mode in VS-2012 and then i use the app shake is not working.
Also tried to Application Deployment tools to deploy the .xap file in device but still not success. 
I use this [shake method](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/cordova_accelerometer_accelerometer.md.html).
this is my jquery code :-

```
// Assess the current acceleration parameters to determine a shake
function assessCurrentAcceleration(acceleration) {
//alert('shake');
    var accelerationChange = {};
    if (previousAcceleration.x !== null) {
        accelerationChange.x = Math.abs(previousAcceleration.x, acceleration.x);
        accelerationChange.y = Math.abs(previousAcceleration.y, acceleration.y);
        accelerationChange.z = Math.abs(previousAcceleration.z, acceleration.z);
    }
    if (accelerationChange.x + accelerationChange.y + accelerationChange.z > 2.5) {
        spin();
        // Shake detected
        if (typeof (shakeCallBack) === "function") {
            alert('shake');
            shakeCallBack();
        }
        shake.stopWatch();
        setTimeout(shake.startWatch, 1000);
        previousAcceleration = { 
            x: null, 
            y: null, 
            z: null
        }
    } else {
        previousAcceleration = {
            x: acceleration.x,
            y: acceleration.y,
            z: acceleration.z
        }
    }
}

  // Handle errors here
   function handleError() {
                   alert('error detect');
       }

    return shake;
    })();
```

Please help me.